# Python piecewise poly1d?

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials, piecewise

Before I attempt to reinvent any wheels, has someone already made a Python class for piecewise polynomials using `numpy.poly1d` (or the like)?  It should take a list of discontinuities and a list of polynomials, and allow all the operations of `poly1d`, or at least (for my purpose) add, subtract, multiply and integrate; I need these as I mean to use piecewise quadratics as basis functions for a least squares fit (to piecewise continuous input rather than discrete input).

(`numpy.piecewise` isn't it: it does not create a persistent object.)

**Update:** Oops, I obtained `piecepoly.py` somehow in November 2010.  (No sign of authorship.  The code is very similar to what I wrote today, but there is a comment "The functions are considered left-continuous," which is not something I'd say.)

Comment: Would spline interpolation do it for you? scipy.interpolate lets you choose the order of the spline.

Comment: `scipy.interpolate.PPoly` and `scipy.interpolate.BPoly` are most of what I want, but apparently neither has `__add__` or `__mul__`, as `poly1d` has.